# How to set odd rows as x axis and even rows as y axis in numbers?

Tags: catalina, numbers

I am trying to create a chart using some data. The odd rows represent the date and time and even rows represent the count. I want to make the odd(date-time) rows as x-axis and even(count) rows as y-axis. Is there any way to do this? I an giving the image of my structure below.

[image]

Please help me to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no way you can chart all that data in Numbers as they are.

First make a copy of that table and then transpose the copy via the **Table > Transpose Rows and Columns** menu at the top. Then cut & paste all date and amount columns below each other respectively. There does not appear to be any other way.